# System.UnauthorizedAccessException in nested Stream calls

Tags: c#, xml, ienumerable, xelement

I am getting `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` in this function

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<XElement>> XMLDisplaySignals()
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sFile.xml");
            XDocument doc;
            try
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                {
                    doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                    IEnumerable<XElement> signals = doc.Descendants("signals");
                    return signals;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

when called in a a `for` loop 5-10 times without a `Sleep`. My for loop looks like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < iItems[0].Count; j++)
            {
                IEnumerable<XElement> signals = await SampleDataSource.XMLDisplaySignals();
                if (signals != null && signals.Descendants("signal").Any())
                {
                    if(!signals.Descendants("signal").Any(x => x.Element("title").Value == iItems[0][j]))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Adding: " + iItems[0][j]);
                        await SampleDataSource.XMLAddXElement(new XElement("signal", new XElement("title", iItems[0][j]), new XElement("body", iItems[1][j])));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Already in");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //handle the bug hardcore
                    await SampleDataSource.XMLAddXElement(new XElement("signal", new XElement("title", iItems[0][j]), new XElement("body", iItems[1][j])));
                }
        }
```

I believe this is happening because I am handling xml writes and reads very fast. Is there a workaround here besides adding `Sleeps`?
`XMLDisplaySignals` looks like this and handles and xml write

```
public static async Task XMLAddXElement(XElement element)
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
            StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("sFile.xml");

            XDocument doc;

            try
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
                {
                    doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                    var signals = doc.Descendants("signals").Single();
                    signals.Add(element);
                    using (var stream2 = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
                    {
                        stream2.SetLength(0);
                        doc.Save(stream2);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
```

P.S. if I add a sleep of 300MS in the for loop, the problem is solved. However as we all know sleep is not a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Sleep is not a solution because you can never be sure how long the operation will take.

You need to lock your resource before using it (i.e. before calling `OpenStreamForReadAsync` in your `XMLDisplaySignals` method) so the operation is not attempted before the resource is released from the previous run.

[This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) explains how to use `AsyncSemaphore` for that purpose.